# How to obtain the unitary operator to get specific partial trace?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-information, density-operator, trace

Is there a unitary $U_{AB}$ such that, for any density operator $\rho$, we have
$${\rm {Tr}}_A \left[U_{AB} \left(\frac{I_A}{2} \otimes \rho_B\right)U_{AB}^{\dagger}\right]= \frac{\rho_B}{2}+\frac{I_B}{4}
\\
{\rm {Tr}}_B \left[U_{AB} \left(\frac{I_A}{2} \otimes \rho_B\right)U_{AB}^{\dagger}\right]= \frac{\rho_A}{2}+\frac{I_A}{4},$$
where $I_A=I_B=I$ is the identity matrix, $\rho_A=\rho_B=\rho$, A and B are both single qubit systems.

I have thought about decomposing $U_{AB}$ to express the partial trace but failed. I also considered about searching for such unitary, but $U_{AB}$ and $\rho$ are both unknown, which holds me back. Any ideas or comments, both in the analytic way or a computation way, would be appreciated.

It seems that symmetry can be used to derive the proof.